# Why can't I access a variable that I have defined in the controller from my view in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm having some trouble accessing my controller variable from the view. In my controller, I did:

```
$this->set('city',$city);
```

And when I try to

```
<?php print_r($city);?>
```

in my view, nothing happens. What might be wrong with my code?

Comment: Missing a `$` in front the initial code.  Assume just a typo.  Beyond that, we'd need to see what else is going on in your controller's action.

Comment: @Dave It was a typo and I just corrected it. I have multiple view files and multiple controller. Do I need to set a relation between the files in order for me to access the variable?

Comment: Are you using the default controller action's view?  For example, if you're in /something/index, are you setting the variable in the SomethingsController and using the Views/Somethings/index.ctp ?

Comment: @Dave Thank you for that.That's why I can't access it. I have /controller/Userscontroller.php and /View/Themed/Site/Users/signup.ctp. Is there anything I can do to get a variable from that controller without renaming?

Comment: Add the code from the function in your controller.